# How can I set an interval inside the custom filter

Tags: angularjs

I created a custom date filter, but I want to set an interval for every second to make it run like a clock ecvery second. Thank you in advance

This is my code.

```
app.filter('DateGap', function() {

  // In the return function, we must pass in a single parameter which will be the data we will work on.
  // We have the ability to support multiple other parameters that can be passed into the filter optionally

  return function update(input, optional1, optional2) {
        var t1 = new Date(input + 'Z');
        var t2 = new Date();
        var dif = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime();
        var Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
        var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);
        var sec_num = Math.floor(Seconds_Between_Dates); // don't forget the second param
        var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if (typeof PenddingHours != "undefined")
            return hours >= PenddingHours ? true : false;

        if (hours < 10) { hours = "0" + hours; }
        if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
        if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0" + seconds; }
        var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
        return time;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will run the filter every second. I am unable to get the filter to work as is, but it logs the updated date in the console so that you can at least see that it is being called each second.

This is just one way to do it.  You could also apply the filter to the `myDate` variable within the controller and skip putting the filter in the markup.

```js
angular.module('intervalExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {

      $scope.myDate = new Date();

      var stop;

      $scope.startTimer = function() {
        stop = $interval(function() {
          $scope.myDate = new Date();
        }, 1000);
      };

      $scope.stopTimer = function() {
        if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
          $interval.cancel(stop);
          stop = undefined;
        }
      };

      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
        $scope.stopTimer();
      });

      $scope.startTimer();
    }
  ])

  .filter('DateGap', function() {

    // In the return function, we must pass in a single parameter which will be the data we will work on.
    // We have the ability to support multiple other parameters that can be passed into the filter optionally

    return function update(input, optional1, optional2) {

      console.log(input);

      var t1 = new Date(input); // + 'Z');
      var t2 = new Date();
      var dif = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime();
      var Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
      var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);
      var sec_num = Math.floor(Seconds_Between_Dates); // don't forget the second param
      var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
      var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

      if (typeof PenddingHours != "undefined")
        return hours >= PenddingHours ? true : false;

      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
      }
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
      }
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
      }
      var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
      return time;
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="intervalExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span> {{ myDate | DateGap }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll just add that setting a timer inside the filter would not be the correct approach. What needs to happen is as above - update the variable every second and then pipe it the filter to format the display. As it's elapsed time you'll likely need to pass in the starting time to the filter also.

Answer (score 0):

You can't asynchronously change the output of a filter in angular 1.x. Filters are pure functions, the output depends only on the input which is a constant date in your case. Use a controller to handle the timing:

```js
angular.module('intervalExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {

      $scope.myTime = 0;

      var startTime = Date.now();
      var timer = $interval(function() {
          $scope.myTime = Date.now() - startTime;
      }, 1000);

      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(timer);
      });
    }
  ])

  .filter('TimeSpan', function() {

    // In the return function, we must pass in a single parameter which will be the data we will work on.
    // We have the ability to support multiple other parameters that can be passed into the filter optionally

    return function update(input, optional1, optional2) {
      var dif = input;
      var Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
      var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);
      var sec_num = Math.floor(Seconds_Between_Dates); // don't forget the second param
      var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
      var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

      if (typeof PenddingHours != "undefined")
        return hours >= PenddingHours ? true : false;

      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
      }
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
      }
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
      }
      var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
      return time;
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="intervalExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span> {{ myTime | TimeSpan }}
  </div>
</div>
```